# Table View Cells showing blanks

Tags: ios, parsing, cell, uitableview

I've got a Table View Cell in .xib. I've got a UILabel and UIImageView in the .xib.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{   
    SchoolsTableViewCell *cell = (SchoolsTableViewCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SchoolsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Before: %@", cell.nameLabel.text);
    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@", [object objectForKey:@"name"]];
    NSLog(@"After: %@", cell.nameLabel.text);

    PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"logo"];
    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         cell.logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
     }];

    return cell;
}
```

As you can see, I have 2 NSLog()s, printing the below:

```
2015-07-08 20:17:26.739 o [1871:108786] Before: (null)

2015-07-08 20:17:26.740 o [1871:108786] After: Name: SMSAS
```

That is expected.

However, on my Simulator, I can only see a blank cell with Name:. It should show SMSAS in the label, and load a logo, but it's not happening. I can pass the object to the next View Controller when the cell is tapped, and it can show in that View Controller.

This is my .m for the cell.

```
@implementation SchoolsTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    self.logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.logoImageView];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake. Anyone care to open my eyes? Thanks!

Comment: I should also mention that I've got the Referencing Outlets connected.

Comment: And I've got the Table View Cell Identifier set to SchoolsTableViewCell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

```
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"SchoolsTableViewCell";
SchoolsTableViewCell *cell = (SchoolsTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SchoolsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ashish, but that doesn't help. I commented off the following, and still it didn't help with the issues :( 

SchoolsTableViewCell *cell = (SchoolsTableViewCell *) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SchoolsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

Comment: Hmm, I can't tell what you've changed, but the updated code doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @EuwingTham `NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SchoolsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: I have SchoolsTableViewCell in the following areas in the .xib:

Custom Class: SchoolsTableViewCell
Module is blank, is that right?

Identity Restoration ID: SchoolsTableViewCell

Table View Cell: SchoolsTableViewCell

Comment: @EuwingTham It should be also in Identifier : SchoolsTableViewCell

Comment: @EuwingTham what you have doing with `[self.contentView addSubview:self.nameLabel];`? you have not designed the cell ?

Comment: Alright! I think you got it! I shouldn't have ANY of the contents in - (void)awakeFromNib. Removing everything there worked!